# MS Graph API: On-prem AD user password reset error

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, reset-password

I'm trying to reset the password of an on-premise user in a hybrid setup. I'm using the [MS Graph API endpoint to update a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-update-the-passwordprofile-of-a-user-to-reset-their-password) to accomplish this task. My Azure application has the necessary API permissions including **Directory.AccessAsUser.All** delegated permission. The application is also granted the **Helpdesk Administrator** role.

But I run into this error when I call the API

[image]

I'm able to reset the password for any Azure AD (cloud) user, but facing this issue only for the on-prem users.

Note that **Password writeback** is enabled in the Azure AD and also verified in the on-prem AD.

If I reset the same user's password via the Azure Portal, the password is synced with the on-prem AD. So this doesn't seem to be an AD configuration issue. But I could be missing something.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

1 .As per error message return the userPrincipleName(UPN) is invalid , first step is to verify the UPN by using GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me, if the user principle is correct ,

2. Next step is to try by adding ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = $false ,we would also like to recommend you to use [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

PATCH [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid%7D)
Content-type: application/json

```
{
  "passwordProfile": {
   "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
   "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
  }
}
```

3. For curiosity could you please check with powershell .
   Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

   $params = @{
   PasswordProfile = @{
   ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = $false
   Password = "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
   }
   }

   Update-MgUser -UserId $userId -BodyParameter $params

Ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#request-2